# How do I add additional view (partial view) when a module public page is constructing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, pyro, pyrocms

Please take a look at this code
     // Create event output
        $this->template->title($event->meta_title)

```
        ->set_metadata('keywords', $event->meta_keywords)
        ->set_metadata('description', $event->meta_description)

        ->set('event', $event_array)

        ->append_metadata('
            <style type="text/css">
                ' . $event->layout->css . '
                ' . $event->css . '
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                ' . $event->js . '
            </script>')

        ->build('event', $this->data);
}
```

This is a partial code from a controller method which construct a page. If I want to load another view (partial view) such partial/form.php and bypass a data to it (). After that, I'd like to display the form after the event's article right before the comments (before the output of. How do I make it happened? Sorry for my silly questions. I'm quite new to PyroCMS, PHP, MVC on practice. :D. I only knew the theory. Now, I let myself to dive in to feel it and try it.

Thanks a bunch.

Merry XMAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a silly question at all. To understand the template library better, check out its specific documentation:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/

PyroCMS uses lots of my libraries, some of which have documentation and some don't. I need to get around to getting it all done but its a massive thankless task and I have plenty on my plate already. :)